# Unable to decode LDPC using Belief Propagation algorithm

Tags: digital-communications, forward-error-correction, ldpc

I'm writing a MATLAB code to decode LDPC codes using the BP algorithm. I'm trying this with a (7,4) code. I tried the message-passing algorithm between variable and check nodes. L_r is the check to variable update information and it is supposed to be a 7x4 matrix. Instead, it is now a 7x7 matrix. L_q is variable to check updates and it is a 4x7 as expected. The output of this code is just giving out the received codeword without correcting the errors.
This is my code.

```
n=7;
k=4;
v=2; % variable node index
q=[0.2, 0.8]; %flipped probability 
H = [1 1 1 0 0 0 0; 0 0 1 1 1 0 0; 0 1 0 0 1 1 0; 1 0 0 1 0 0 1];
c=[  1     0     1     1     1     1     1]; %codeword
received_message=[  1     0     0     1     1     1     0];
L_c= zeros(size(received_message));
for i = 1:numel(received_message)
    bit = received_message(i) + 1;
    L_c(i) = log((1 - q(bit)) / q(bit));
end
max_iterations = 50;
for iteration = 1:max_iterations
    % Update Variable-to-Check Messages
    for i = 1:k
        check_nodes = find(H(:, i));
        for j = check_nodes
            L_q(i, j) =L_c(i) + sum(L_r(:, i)) - L_r(j, i);
        end
    end
        % Update Check-to-Variable Messages
    for j = 1:size(H,1)
        variable_nodes = find(H(j, :));
        for i = variable_nodes
            L_r(j, i) = 2 * atanh(prod(tanh(0.5 * L_q(variable_nodes ~= i, j))));
        end
    end
end 
C_i = find(H(v, :));
for p=1:numel(received_message)
L_Q(p)= L_c(p)+ sum(L_r(C_i)); 
end 
for w=1:numel(received_message)
    if L_Q(w) <= 0 
        decoded_message(w)=1;
    else  
        decoded_message(w)=0;
    end
end
```